# Pandas - Error when applying isin to a Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter a Dataframe with a few values as below:

```
df_new = df[[['bill_no']].isin('1002','1005')]
```

This throws an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need filter by column `df['bill_no']` with values in list `['1002','1005']`:

```
df_new = df[df['bill_no'].isin(['1002','1005'])]
```